# Did my Chromecast and SmartTV team-up to port scan in my network?

Tags: networking, security, firewall, chromecast

Since a day or two I noticed suspicious activities from my Chromecast and Samsung SmartTV in my Firewall logs.

```
S Tue Feb 12 22:12:01 2019 p4 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=... SRC={SMART-TV-IP} DST={MY-PC-IP} LEN=364 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=49083 DPT=57525 LEN=344 
S Tue Feb 12 22:12:01 2019 p4 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=... SRC={CHROMECAST-IP} DST={MY-PC-IP} LEN=547 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=43783 DPT=57525 LEN=527 
S Tue Feb 12 22:12:02 2019 p4 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=... SRC={SMART-TV-IP} DST={MY-PC-IP} LEN=364 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44931 DPT=57525 LEN=344 
S Tue Feb 12 22:12:02 2019 p4 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=... SRC={CHROMECAST-IP} DST={MY-PC-IP} LEN=547 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=43100 DPT=57525 LEN=527 
S Tue Feb 12 22:13:55 2019 p4 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] Some Broadcast form my Router...
S Tue Feb 12 22:13:58 2019 p4 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] Some Broadcast form my Router...
S Tue Feb 12 22:14:01 2019 p4 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=... SRC={SMART-TV-IP} DST={MY-PC-IP} LEN=364 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44124 DPT=51786 LEN=344 
S Tue Feb 12 22:14:01 2019 p4 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=... SRC={CHROMECAST-IP} DST={MY-PC-IP} LEN=547 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=54514 DPT=51786 LEN=527 
S Tue Feb 12 22:14:02 2019 p4 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=... SRC={SMART-TV-IP} DST={MY-PC-IP} LEN=364 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=40748 DPT=51786 LEN=344 
S Tue Feb 12 22:14:02 2019 p4 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=... SRC={CHROMECAST-IP} DST={MY-PC-IP} LEN=547 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=41755 DPT=51786 LEN=527 
S Tue Feb 12 22:16:00 2019 p4 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] Some Broadcast form my Router...
S Tue Feb 12 22:16:01 2019 p4 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=... SRC={SMART-TV-IP} DST={MY-PC-IP} LEN=364 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=57653 DPT=54175 LEN=344 
S Tue Feb 12 22:16:01 2019 p4 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=... SRC={CHROMECAST-IP} DST={MY-PC-IP} LEN=547 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=33120 DPT=54175 LEN=527 
S Tue Feb 12 22:16:02 2019 p4 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=... SRC={SMART-TV-IP} DST={MY-PC-IP} LEN=364 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=39294 DPT=54175 LEN=344
and so on..
```

In the beginning they simultaneously scanned the same destination port (see above, "DPT"). After a while they went for different ports. The behavior started suddenly and has not stopped since.

I thought this is related to the recent [CastHack](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2019/01/04/dont-fall-victim-to-the-chromecast-hackers-heres-what-to-do/) attacks, but my devices are working fine and no one has observed and documented the same behavior that I see.

I live on a remote place and my TV has LAN only.. So I assume it is not coming from my Wifi.

UPNP is disabled, no ports were exposed for the TV or Chromecast.

**Does anyone else with a SmartTV or Chromecast see the same traffic in their network?**

Comment: Chromecast uses the [Device discovery protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromecast#Device_discovery_protocols) to scan the network. This might be normal behavior.

Comment: @harrymc: I thought so too but the ports do not match mDNS or DIAL protocol. I cropped these out form the log above as "Some Broadcast form my Router...". Furthermore, it bothers me that it is so consistent and the ports range down to >=30000 so far.

Comment: It [seems like](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85136/creating-ufw-rule-to-allow-application-to-use-dynamic-ports) the Chromecast extension uses ephemeral ports in an unrestricted manner.